# Error adding panel to usercontrol: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, winforms, panel

I have a problem. I am trying to access a panel in a user control.When I access it in a form it works. Earlier on I did this.

I accessed a panel in a form from a user control and it worked. Below is the code I used:

```
Form1 form = Application.OpenForms.OfType<Form1>().FirstOrDefault();
            form.Panel1.Controls.Clear();
            ManageControl user = new ManageControl();
            form.Panel1.Controls.Add(user);
```

But when I try to use the very same concept in a user control it does not work.

It throws a null error: `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

Below is the code:

```
//this is in ManageControl.cs
public Panel Panel2
        {
            get { return panelmanage; }
        }
```

//this is in another userControl.Trying to access panelImage

```
 ManageControl form = Application.OpenForms.OfType<ManageControl>().FirstOrDefault();
            form.Panel2.Controls.Clear();//it throws the error here
            ReportControl user = new ReportControl();
            form.Panel2.Controls.Add(user);
```

What am I doing wrong because I am using the same concept?

**EDIT**:

This is my ManageControl.cs

```
 public partial class ManageControl : UserControl
    {

        public ManageControl()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            
        }

        public Panel Panel2
        {
            get { return panelmanage; }
           
        }
```

This is how I try to access it in BookingListControl

```
public partial class BookingListControl : UserControl
    {
        ManageControl form = Application.OpenForms.OfType<ManageControl>().FirstOrDefault();
        public BookingListControl()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void linkLabel1_LinkClicked(object sender, LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs e)
        {
            ManageControl form = Application.OpenForms.OfType<ManageControl>().FirstOrDefault();
         
            ReportControl user = new ReportControl();
            form.Panel2.Controls.Add(user);
        }
```

Comment: Well, `panelmanage` must be null. Did you assign it?

Comment: I added it by dragging it from tool box and placing it on the usercontrol.But why does it work when i access it from the user control i placed it in.I did the exact same thing for both panels in form1 and ManageControl.The other works but the other does not.Really confused now.

Comment: I'm guessing you are getting a NullReferenceException. Can you tell us what is null? Btw, this is a *very* odd way of accessing controls so we may have an XY problem here as well. Adding a bit of context could help solve the bigger issue.

Comment: when I debug, form is null, I then get the error in the following line."form.Panel2.Controls.Clear();".The reason I try to access them like this, is that I want to avoid forms popping up, and just use one form.

Answer (score 1):

`ManageControl` is a `UserControl` not a `Form`. Thus, when you look for open forms of type `ManageControl`, you get nothing (no surprises here). Then, we you call `FirstOrDefault` it returns null (since there were no matching elements in the empty collection), and your next line blows up.

This approach is doomed from the start, because even if you had a whole bunch of forms overlaying each other and *could* make it work (bad idea), it would break once you had *two* `ManageControl` objects and needed to access the second.

Instead, first ask yourself, "Why do my UserControl objects need to access each other?". This is an important question, because in general `UserControl`s are independent. They likely have methods to give data back to their parent, but thats it. They certainly don't interact with other UserControls.

If you decide that you *really need* this dependency, then I would pass the parent `Form` object to both `UserControl`s and have a public property on the `Form` that allows them to see the other `UserControl`. From here you can access it normally (without needing any `OpenForms` nonsense). Honestly though, this is a massive code smell and it sounds like the whole design should be looked at to see where you have dependencies that could be removed.

To do this you need to expose the `ManageControl` on the form:

```
public class ParentForm : Form
{
    public ManageControl Manager { get { return manageControlInstance; } }
    ...
}
```

Then access it in your child control. The easiest way would be through the `Parent` property, but you could pass it on the constructor or an `Init` function as well.

```
public class ChildControl : UserControl
{
     private void SomeFunction()
     {
         (Parent as ParentForm).Manager.Panel2.Controls.Add(new ReportControl());
     }
}
```

The code's pretty ugly, and I wouldn't recommend it (its also not safe if you put the `ChildControl` into anything other than a `ParentForm`). That being said it *would* work.

Comment: I think I partially understand what you implying.But I do not know how to achieve that.May you please shed some light.

Comment: I'd be happy to. Which part is confusing?

Comment: How would I pass "panelmanage" to the Form in order to access it in the other usercontrol as I intended to do?

Comment: See my added code. I'm still not saying you *should* do it, but this should get you working.

Comment: @user2893681 Lets discuss this in chat: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59970/discussion-of-http-stackoverflow-com-questions-25494639-error-adding-panel-to-u

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the NullReferenceException occurred based on accessing the "Panel2" property, your issue is that "panelmanage" is null. Is the code that finds and populates "form.Panel2" in a form or control constructor? If so, try restructuring it to run after ManageControl is fully initialized - perhaps by putting it into a Loaded event.

Comment: But then what is "manageControlInstance".You are really loosing me now.I am trying to use panelmanage which is in ManageControl.I suppose I cannot see it from here.

Comment: Now you are really loosing me BradleyDotNET.I have a form: Form1, two userControls: ManageUserControl and BookingUsercontrol.I want to access a panel in ManageUserControl from BookingControl.ManageControl is not in Form1.